# Position Independent Code on STM32 - pointers

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, fpic, position-independent-code

I've managed to build and run position independent code on STM32. Vector table and GOT are patched. Everything works, but I have problem with such code.

```
double myAdd(double x) {
   return x + 0.1;
}

double (*ptrmyAdd)(double) = &myAdd;

char* myString = "foo bar";

int main() {
   ...
   printf("%s %2.2f\n", myString, ptrmyAdd(0.1));
   ...
}
```

I works only when application has no offset (relative to flash base address). Reason is obvious, `myString` and `ptrmyAdd` points to .rodata and .text without proper offset.

What can I do? I can reinitialize pointers at runtime.

```
int main() {
   ...
   myString = "foo bar";
   ptrmyAdd = &myAdd;
   printf("%s %2.2f\n", myString, ptrmyAdd(0.1));
   ...
}
```

And it works fine with any offset.

To fix pointers which points to .rodata I can spare some RAM and move .rodata to RAM, but I can't move .text to RAM.

I can also run through section .data at startup and update all values which looks like flash addresses, but it's dangerous.

Is there any way to fix those pointers before main()?

Why I need position independent code. System looks like this...

```
*--------*
|        |
|        |
|  APP2  | Application bank 2
|        |
|        |
*--------* 0x08084000
|        |
|        |
|  APP1  | Application bank 1
|        |
|        |
*--------* 0x08008000
|        |
|  INFO  | Application info area
|        |
*--------* 0x08007800
|        |
|  LDR   | Bootloader area
|        |
*--------* 0x08000000
```

Bootloader downloads application image via y-modem protocol to first avaliable bank marked as "not active". Bootloader sets new bank as "active" and "valid" and previous "active" bank as "not active". After reset bootloader start application from "active" bank. Before application starts, bootloader activates IWDG.

If reset was from IWDG, bootloader checks "not active" bank for valid application. If it contains "valid" application, bootloader marks active bank as "invalid" and swaps active banks.

User performing an update doesn't know which bank is free. Bootloader decides which bank to use.

Comment: Before main()? I thought the whole point of position independent code was that it basically doesn't have a .data section separately from .text, it's attached above or below code, and all references to data in .data section become PC-relative, so you can load and use that code at any moment at runtime from RAM. But since you want .text to remain in Flash, but .data to be in RAM...You have to do some runtime binding somehow. Have you considered using another separate section for that data? It actually seems to me this is the situation where you do NOT want position independent code

Comment: I have simple bootloader and two virtual banks for application. Bootloader decides which bank is free to use. I is easier to use single application image for two different banks.

Comment: You may want to include a proper detailed description of how exactly that works into the question, because you didn't give any specifics, so I have no idea what to do with this random inapplicable information. This seems like it could be crucial to figuring out what to do, but one needs specifics for that. What is loaded where and when by the bootloader. Write a couple of paragraphs about it.

Comment: I've seen couple of attempts of PIC on CMx claiming "almost works", "only minor issues need to be ironed out"; yet never heard of reports of success. I'd recommend to contemplate alternatives: entirely different approach to loading (copy from loaded upper to active lower image); built both "upper" and "lower" image and make loader handshaking with master to ask for appropriate from 2 images; use STM32 model with dual-bank FLASH (which are intended exactly for this sort of usage).

Comment: I've compiled newlib with -fpic. I encountered a problem with the sprintf function and floats. Reason was that some elements of struct __global_locale were pointing to .rodata. Moving .rodata to ram solved problem for floats, but still there are some elements that points to .text, so sooner or later I will encounter a situation where the my code will crash.

Comment: So I have implemented the same and just eliminated them by scanning the binary for absolute pointers.  It is a lot of work and in retrospect, I would just create two images.  One for position 1 and one for position 2 and just make the boot loader ask for the correct one.  Another issues is computed gotos and labels feature of gcc will break with PIC.  Also array of strings are a problem.  I just avoided the problem by scanning the binary for absolute pointers.  As you say, runtime patching is dangerous, but not if they don't exist.

Comment: The two images solution could be distributed with a 'bsdiff' type of format.  The the boot loader just needs to patch position 1 to run in position 2.  For some cases, a code generation tool can help.  Example `gperf` has '-P' and '-pic'.  So search for 'shared library support' in any dependant tooling.

Comment: I am facing the same, problem, did you manage to obtain a solution?